# Infer type hints for dictionary structure from class attributes definition

Tags: python, dictionary, mypy, python-typing

I'm trying to figure out a way to create *precise* types for a function that returns class attributes as an **immutable dictionary**.

For the sake of example, let's say we have a foreign class called "A", by foreign I mean it comes from a library that I don't own, but it has typing stubs such as:

```
class A:
    name: str
    content: str
    age: int
```

Now, I want to create a function that returns dictionary, so that its shape is exactly as that class' available attributes. I am able to get list of fields and their corresponding types through `typing.get_type_hints()`, such as:

```
>>> from typing import get_type_hints
>>> obj = A()
>>> get_type_hints(obj)
{'name': <class 'str'>, 'content': <class 'str'>, 'age': <class 'int'>}
```

Now, what I'd like to do is to create a function that is fully and strongly typed:

```
def convert_object_to_dict(_obj: A) -> frozendict[str, Any]:
    ... # Let's ignore the implementation detail here, this is just example
```

(I know frozendict is not a type, but let's assume it is)

If I call it with an object that has all the fields defined, it should return a dictionary that has three keys, with their names exactly as early defined `class A`, for the sake of argument let's assume that it will always return all the attributes defined in a class.

The obvious return type that I can use is `frozendict[str, Any]`, however, this doesn't tell mypy nor IDE what keys to expect. I could perhaps make it more precise, by using Union of all the types I expect, but again, that means I have to maintain it and feels redundant if `get_type_hints` is able to tell me exactly what is there. Alternative solution could be making TypedDict of the same shape as that class, but this would be a nightmare to maintain and would make typing more annoying than useful.

What I'd like to do is, something similar to this:

```
def convert_object_to_dict(_obj: A) -> TypedDict[A]:
    ...
```

So that if I call this function, mypy will be able to tell what shape the dictionary is, and so what keys should be possible to be used with other functions later on. It should raise an error if I try to use a key which doesn't exist in some later full typed contexts.

`TypedDict[A]` in this case, should create a TypedDict, whose fields are exactly as these available in class `A`.

Is it possible to do with MyPy / Python typing at all?

Comment: Do you want the read only-behaviour to be enforced at runtime or just type hinted?

Comment: `TypedDict[A]` is not possible; you'd have to define (and maintain) the `TypedDict` yourself. Dynamically obtaining the annotations will not work for static type checkers for obvious reasons. There is no mechanism available in the Python typing system for defining a mapping-like type via the attributes of a class. I am wondering what the premise is here. What purpose would such a function even serve? I mean why not just use the object `A` as is? What do you need the dictionary for? If you need dynamic access to attributes via strings, you have `getattr`.

Comment: It is possible, but will require custom `mypy` plugin - for example, start with `Annotated`, then in `get_type_analyze_hook` process that annotation to create a `TypedDict` node, add it to global namespace - it should be possible. However, there is no built-in way and no simple solution, plus it's highly questionable whether you really need this. What is the reason to maintain TypedDict and class at the same time? If it is like API response, then probably specific typing is redundant. If it is used within the application - why serialize to dict when you can keep using the original class?

Comment: A real world example of that is when there is validate method on drf serializer, it accepts `attrs` argument which is a dictionary that has all the values same as they are defined in the class, I wanted to use mypy to make sure I always use the right keys from that dictionary, and in case I change the serializer, I would like to catch the usage errors before they cause an actual issue.

Comment: I'd just add simple runtime assert for that (probably via a helper function, like `assert all(k in dir(target_cls) for k in given_dict)`). This way you can be much more flexible without complicationg things too much. Perhaps I'd turn it into a method decorator accepting model class as parameter.